# Strange cause for 'MySQL server has gone away'

Tags: php, mysql, database

Despite many questions regarding this MySQL error, I haven't found a solution to my problem.

My (PHP) application requires the generation of a DAL (database access layer). This is done through a php script called from the command line. This script reads all tables from the information schema and generates files according to that schema.

This has been working for as long as I can remember, until recently. Every time I start this generation process, my 'normal' application loses connection to the MySQL server.

The strange thing is, that I can however connect to the database using a program such as Sequel Pro. Same database, same connection settings, same machine.

Also, when I try to restart MySQL on the command line using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart` I get the error:

`ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found`

Then Starting MySQL takes forever before I kill it. The only solution I found is to completely reboot my computer. It then works fine again until I rerun the generation script.

So, résumé, I've got 2 problems:

1. When I run the script using the information schema, my normal application loses the ability to connect to the MySQL server, while other applications still can.
2. When that happens, I'm unable to restart MySQL to fix the problem.

The second problem is obviously way less important than the first one. I'd rather not have to restart MySQL at all.

**What the generation script does:**

First:

```
SELECT *
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() %s AND SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 1, 1)!='_'"
```

Then a loop in PHP to loop over all tables.

Then this:

```
SELECT * 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
                AND TABLE_NAME=:tableName
```

The rest of the script then generates PHP files from that information.

Comment: Can we see your generation script, or if it's too long, at least the part when the problem arises?

Comment: The generation script runs flawlessly. The problem is that the application (apart from the generation script) fails to connect to MySQL when the generation script has run.

Comment: The rebooting part is suuuper suspect and I can't think of an explanation. I have seen messed up indexes cause long or failing restarts. Do your mysqld logs have anything to say? I'm curious what the generation script does as well, to see what it could potentially be breaking.

Comment: I'm going to throw it  2 guesses. 1. Your maximum packet size is too small, increase it. 2. Your innodb log files are too small, increase them.

Comment: I updated my answer with info about the generation script.

Comment: I'll try that. But could there be any sensitive reason for my application to be the only thing having troubles connecting to MySQL?

Comment: And my second problem may be unrelated or differently related. The restart never works, not even when my application is up and running.

Comment: Do you have a lot of data (columns) in those tables? It looks to me that you are selecting everything and as your database grows you do not have enough memory. So mysql crashes and corrupts some log file or temp file so it is not able to autostart again. But I am not a guru in MySQL and may be completely wrong.

Comment: That may be the cause. 300 tables in total, and some tables have up to 50 columns. My MySQL version was old anyway, so I reinstalled everything and it's smooth again now.